# How to get JavaScript response into HTML

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, arcgis

I've got a HTML file which requires a token to access some data (from ArcGIS Online). A separate JavaScript file should call the service and get the token. The token then needs passing into the HTML file somehow, which is the bit I'm uncertain on.

In any case, code:

**JavaScript file (GetAToken.js)**

```
var request = require('request'); // npm install request

// generate a token with your client id and client secret
function getToken(callback)
{
    request.post(
    {
        url: 'https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/oauth2/token/',
        json: true,
        form:
        {
            'f': 'json',
            'client_id': '<<MY CLIENT_ID>>',
            'client_secret': '<<MY CLIENT_SECRET>>',
            'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
            'expiration': '1440'
        }
    }, function (error, response, body)
    {
        console.log(body.access_token);
        callback(body.access_token);
    });
}
```

**And the relevant bits from the HTML**

```
<script src="GetAToken.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="getToken()">
<div class="embed-container">
    <iframe width="500"
            height="400"
            frameborder="0"
            scrolling="no"
            marginheight="0"
            marginwidth="0"
            title="Test Map" src="//MyMap.maps.arcgis.com/apps/webappviewer/index.html?id=LongMapID?token=I_Need_My_Token_Here&amp;extent=1,-1,1,-1&amp;zoom=true&amp;scale=true&amp;search=true&amp;searchextent=true&amp;legend=true&amp;basemap_gallery=true&amp;disable_scroll=true&amp;theme=light">
    </iframe>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

If you look within the div in the HTML, that's where I need my token to go. The JavaScript apparently returns a value called `access_token`, and is written using node.js

**EDIT**

New GetAToken.js

```
const request = require('request'); // npm install request
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// generate a token with your client id and client secret
//function getToken(callback)
app.get('/GetAToken', (req, res) => {
    request.post(
    {
        url: 'https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/oauth2/token/',
        json: true,
        form:
        {
            'f': 'json',
            'client_id': '<<MY_CLIENT_ID>>',
            'client_secret': '<<MY_CLIENT_SECRET>>',
            'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
            'expiration': '1440'
        }
    }, function (error, response, body) {
        console.log(body.access_token);
        callback(body.access_token);
    });
});
app.listen(80);
```

Updated HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link href="https://esri.github.io/calcite-bootstrap/assets/css/calcite-bootstrap-open.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
        .footer
        {
            height: 6.25rem;
        }
    </style>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://esri.github.io/calcite-bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.17/"></script>
    <script src="GetAToken.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if(xhttp.readyState === 4 && xhttp.status === 200)
            {
                var responseJSON = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
                var token = responseJSON.token;
                alert(token);
            }
        }
        xhttp.open("GET", "GetAToken", true);
        xhttp.send();    

    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <style>
        .embed-container
        {
            position: relative;
            padding-bottom: 50%;
            height: 0;
            max-width: 100%;
        }
        .embed-container iframe, .embed-container object, .embed-container iframe
        {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        small
        {
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 40;
            bottom: 0;
            margin-bottom: -15px;
        }
    </style>
    <div class="embed-container">
        <iframe width="500"
                height="400"
                frameborder="0"
                scrolling="no"
                marginheight="0"
                marginwidth="0"
                title="Test Map" src="//MyMap.maps.arcgis.com/apps/webappviewer/index.html?id=MyLongID&amp;extent=1,-1,1,-1&amp;zoom=true&amp;scale=true&amp;search=true&amp;searchextent=true&amp;legend=true&amp;basemap_gallery=true&amp;disable_scroll=true&amp;theme=light">
        </iframe>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is `GetAToken` running on the server or the client?

Comment: I'm unsure. I'm pretty new to JavaScript. It is in the same folder as my HTML at the moment, and I'll want it to run on the internet eventually.

Comment: It should run on the server because it has the secret key.

Comment: In that case, yes, it'll be on the server. Eventually. As I say, at the moment it's just on my computer.

Comment: I can suggest to use EHTML to map json response from the server to the html: https://github.com/Guseyn/EHTML

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to make the response of that request to arcgis available to the client somehow. Here's an example using express:

```
const request = require('request'); // npm install request
const express = require('express'); // npm install express
const app = express();

app.get('/get-a-token', (req, res) => 
{
        request.post(
        {
                url: 'https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/oauth2/token/',
                json: true,
                form:
                {
                        'f': 'json',
                        'client_id': '<<MY CLIENT_ID>>',
                        'client_secret': '<<MY CLIENT_SECRET>>',
                        'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
                        'expiration': '1440'
                }
        }, function (error, response, body)
        {
                console.log(body.access_token);
                res.json({token: body.access_token});
        });
});

app.listen(80);
```

Then on the client, you could do something like this to get the value from the server:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // You may want to move this to another file..
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhttp.readyState === 4 && xhttp.status === 200) {
            var responseJSON = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
            var token = responseJSON.token;

            var iframe = document.querySelectorAll('iframe')[0]
            iframe.src = "//MyMap.maps.arcgix.com/apps/webappviewer/index.html?id=LongMapID?token=" + token + "&amp;extent=1,-1,1,-1&amp;zoom=true&amp;scale=true&amp;search=true&amp;searchextent=true&amp;legend=true&amp;basemap_gallery=true&amp;disable_scroll=true&amp;theme=light"
        }
    }
    xhttp.open("GET", "http://yournodeserver.com/get-a-token", true);
    xhttp.send();
</script>
```

You might want to do something to protect the `/get-a-token` route from being accessed by sites other than yours.

If you are serving your html file with node/express too then you could solve this by inserting the token to the html before serving it to the client instead

Comment: Unfortunately the console.log is coming back with an `Uncaught Error: undefinedModule` in the init.js:19 and also `Uncaught ReferenceError: send is not defined` in the HTML.

Comment: can you post the code you're using? The console.log won't log an error - only the value of access_token, but there may be some other code throwing it.

Comment: I'm basically using the code above. However, I'm uncertain whether I've installed node.js correctly.

Comment: In addition, I got rid of the `Uncaught ReferenceError: send is not defined` error - that was my fault. Still getting the `Uncaught Error: undefinedModule` though.